# Create duplicate records in a lookup table, for each unique value of a column id

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a lookup table with id(primary key), name, value and branchId as the columns. Currently I have a set of data with the branchId being the same for the entire records. I need to duplicate the data with same values for the name and value columns, but a different value of branchId in the same table.

Any help with the query/script to achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `id` datatype `IDENTITY` or simple `INT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is an `IDENTITY`, its values will be produced automatically:

```
INSERT INTO tableX                    --- the name of your table
    (name, value, branchID)
SELECT 
    name, value, 23                   --- branch to be added
FROM
    tableX
WHERE
    branchID = 12 ;                   --- the existing branch
```

For a set of branchID values, you can `CROSS` join to an existing a table (or create one on the fly):

```
INSERT INTO tableX                    
    (name, value, branchID)
SELECT 
    t.name, t.value, ins.branchID
FROM
        tableX AS t
    CROSS JOIN
        ( VALUES
            (1), (5), (7), (9), (10)      --- branchIDs to be inserted
        ) AS ins (branchID)
WHERE
    t.branchID = 12 ;                     --- the existing branchID
```

Comment: Ypercube...This gets me closer. But rather than hard-cording each new value (like 23 in your example), how can I loop this for a range of values ? Would it be possible to generalize it?

Comment: You mean you want to insert/duplicate these rows for multiple branches?

Comment: That's right. The branch range would be a set of values lets say {1, 5, 7,9, 10}.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into LookupTable
(
    name,
    value,
    branchId
)
select
    name,
    value,
    'BranchId2'
from LookupTable
where branchId = 'BranchId1'
```

Comment: As I replied to Ypercube, its the similar response I got from you both. Rather than hard-cording each new value how can we do this for a range of values ? Would it be possible to generalize it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  id, name, value, branchId, 
row_number() over (partition by name, value order by id) new_branch_id 
from tablename
```